# How to create a plugin for Slack that aggregates updates into one single channel?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'd like to create a plugin for Slack that creates a dedicated `"feed"` channel.

- This channel will aggregate all updates from the rest of channels.
- In this way, users won't have to click on each channel to read the newly added posts.

Is there any plugin that resembles this behaviour?

Comment: I am voting to close, because asking for 3rd party plugins is out of scope for SO. Nevertheless if you want to develop such an app yourself I can confirm that this is possible (as long as you stick with public channels). Would recommend to look into Events API on how to get message events.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting idea. You could let users subscribe which channels they wish to watch. Then, you could collect all the messages from those channels and post it to the aggregator channel.

There are some 3-rd party apps that go one level up by understanding the discussions, preparing a summary using machine learning. I'm interested to join if you are planning to develop such an app.